# Prolog type definition in swi-prolog

Tags: types, prolog, definition, visual-prolog

in visual prolog there is "domains" section in a prolog program in which you can define types. Is there any similar thing in swi-prolog?

In visual prolog a type is defined like:

```
domains
NewType = thing1; thing2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  But there is mode declaration in [Mercury](http://mercurylang.org/about.html). Mercury is more than Prolog; it is a [functional-logic](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Emh/FLP/) language. Mercury still has a lot of Prolog syntax.

SWI-Prolog is a standard Prolog.  It only uses mode declarations in documentation[1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%275%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/pldoc.html%27%29%29) as information for the users. Such declarations can be placed in comments of modules for documentation-parsing programs to compile.

In standard Prologs, outside of comments, such declarations are only allowed (and reqired) in very special situations. The [block](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Block-Declarations.html#Block-Declarations) predicate of Sicstus Prolog for instance requires them.

*Block/1* is used for co-routing(lazy evaluation, delay etc.).  I've only seen `block` used in one program in my life, PAKCS[2](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), an interpreter for another functional-logic language.  When the interpreter was ported to SWI, `block/1` was not used.

[1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%275%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/pldoc.html%27%29%29) *Type and mode declarations* in SWI Source Documentation
[2](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/) PAKCS, a program using the `block/1` predicate (PAKCS is an implementation of the *curry* language.)

Answer (score 7):

While SWI-Prolog doesn't support types in a capacity quite like what you're asking for, it is worth noting that it does indeed support a simple 'type' mechanism through the use of term specification via the [record/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/record.pl) predicate in the `record` library.

This predicate allows you to specify a reasonably complex term 'type' (pattern) using a particular term specification language, and interprets it to automatically generate predicates used to perform creation (via a constructor predicate), modification via 'setter' predicates and accessors via 'getter' predicates on term instances, all by way of term-expansion with a particular predicate naming convention.

This is particularly useful when writing Prolog code that passes around reasonably complex term structures, as it provides you with a rudimentary type checking capability which Prolog typically lacks (natively). I've used this on many a large-scale Prolog project where interfaces are designed before implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I remembered reading about types for Swi & Yap prolog. Here's a website with a "Hindley-Milner Type Checker for Prolog:"

[Types for Prolog - Mercury-style type declarations and predicate signatures](http://tomschrijvers.blogspot.com/2008/02/types-for-prolog.html)

[Prolog Type Checker library](http://tomschrijvers.blogspot.com/2009/12/new-release-of-prolog-type-checker.html)